# Convert JSON String to Object - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON String like this.

```
{"label":"label","label1":"67041","label2":"745","label3":"45191","label4":"11‌​464"}
```

I wanted to convert it to object like this

```
[{"label":"label","label1":"67041","label2":"745","label3":"45191","label4":"11‌​464"}]
```

I did figure that out like this.

```
'[' + {"label":"label","label1":"67041","label2":"745","label3":"45191","label4":"11‌​464"} + ']'
```

And using `$.parseJSON()` to make it a JSON.

But instead of concatenating. Is there any elegant way to do it?

If so please do share me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Uhm, you're doing what now? **http://jsfiddle.net/UDzrW/**

Comment: @Jan - The was very clear to others and I've even got the correct answer for it. Why did you put this hold?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to push that object into an array,

```
var xObj = {"label":"label","label1":"67041","label2":"745","label3":"45191","label4":"11‌​464"};
var xArr = [];
xArr.push(xObj);

console.log(JSON.stringify(xArr)); //[{"label":"label","label1":"67041","label2":"745","label3":"45191","label4":"11‌​464"}];
```

Comment: ... And then? The asker wants JSON, not an actual array.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's what I was expecting for. upvote by me. I'm not the downvoter.

Comment: Wait, do you not want a json = string? Could you clarify that in the question, please?  Here's my undownvote. I also vote the question as unclear. I give up.

Comment: Well I'm a newbie. I guess so my question is correct. When I did see the console.log. It was reflecting as `Object` ofc. And the answer provided by him also reflecting as object.

Comment: @UnknownUser just gave the way to check the result in console. please see the updated answer. :)

Comment: I did it already. And what you provided was of course correct. And I need to private message. How can I contact you?

Comment: @unknown this answer produces an array. I thought you wanted a string representing that array?

Comment: @JanDvorak if he/she want the result as string, then he/she can use `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: @Jan - I've asked to convert the JSON string to object and I'm getting as object when I do `console.log()` with the answer he provided.

Comment: @unknown ok... After rereading... Are you trying to do `[obj]`, `JSON.parse(obj)` or maybe `[JSON.parse(obj)]`? In any case, this answer starts with an object, not a string.

Comment: Well. I actually don't know what it is. I'm a newbie not that much of javascript guy. Just made the header as with the data I saw in the console.log

Comment: Oh well. I guess every answer is equally valid when the asker  himself has no idea what he actually wants.

Comment: @JanDvorak yes that's absolutely right.

Comment: I still don't understand how it is tagged as using jquery but wont just do this: var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( '{ "name": "John" }' ); to quickly solve it?

Comment: Actually, when the asker doesn't know, how can we? And being unclear is a close reason on Stack Exchange.

Comment: thanks alot..its work

Answer (score 15):

JSONParse like this: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

```
var jsonobj = $.parseJSON(jsonString);
```

There is no need to convert it into an object first just parse the string into a var and it wil lbe an object for you to use.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without using jQuery?

Comment: Yes i would of thought so, but this question is tagged as jquery so I don't know why you wouldn't use it.

Comment: People that don't use jquery might find this question anyways. It's always nice to provide an alternative.

Comment: I suppose, if that was the case and JQuery wasn't an option I would of used JSON.Parse (Providing that the browser was compatable): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: As of jQuery 3.0, $.parseJSON is deprecated. To parse JSON strings use the native JSON.parse method instead.
https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Answer (score 5):

You could use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

```
JSON.parse('{"p": 5}')//Not jquery need it
```

And if array:

```
JSON.parse('[{"p": 5}]')
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe JSON.parse(str) can do it, but it's not valid on all the browsers.

Comment: I was not able to use it. I was getting error as when I used JSON.parse.

Comment: There's a shim available to provide it in browsers that don't support it. I beleive it is called JSON2.js by Douglas Crockford.

Comment: Yes, you can use json2.js to polyfill the browser which doesn't support it. I am pretty sure JSON.parse does the job. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse