# Converting serialized form data into json object using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to get data from my form and then send it to a servlet. But then I notice that the json object that I am getting after serializing my form is not a valid json object. What could I be doing wrong? This is what I tried so far.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on("click", "#check", function() { // When HTML DOM "click" event is invoked on element with ID "somebutton", execute the following function...
      event.preventDefault();
      var data = $("#register").serialize().split("&");
      var obj={};
        for(var key in data)
        {
            console.log(data[key]);
            obj[data[key].split("=")[0]] = data[key].split("=")[1];
        }

        console.log(obj);
// store json string
     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "HomeServlet",
            dataType: "text",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data:{"res":obj},
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            },
            error:function(){
                console.log("error");
            },

        });
});

</script>
```

The json object that i am getting from the form is -

```
{
    apiname: "jdjdj",
    apiendpoint: "sdjsdj",
    apiversion: "djdjd",
    source: "internet"
}
```

This is what I want -

```
{
    "apiname": "jdjdj",
    "apiendpoint": "sdjsdj",
    "apiversion": "djdjd",
    "source": "internet"
}
```

Comment: JSON.stringify({ res: obj})

Comment: try var new_data = JSON.stringify(data);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert form data to JavaScript object with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-javascript-object-with-jquery)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert JS object to JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162749/convert-js-object-to-json-string)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert JSON String to Object - jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23311182/convert-json-string-to-object-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the json you Got .

Just stringify it to get the desired object

```
var myJSON1 = JSON.stringify(data);
```

this will work

Answer (score 0):

YOu may try it

```
JSON.stringify(json_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, your passing a raw javascript object. 
What you must do is convert this object prior to sending it over the wire.

```
JSON.stringify(json_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

please use `JSON.stringify(obj, undefined, 2);`

Answer (score -1):

Instead of this foreach loop only use serializeArray() then json_parse() these two functions will work for you.

```
var data = $("#register").serializeArray();
var obj= JSON_parse(JSON_stringify(data));
```

Comment: JSON_parse() and JSON_stringify are incorrect. It's JSON.parse() and JSON.stringify()